# Make a headers in UITableView stack rather than push?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My section header sticks around at the top until the next section header comes along.. then it pushes it off the screen.  In most cases, this is the expected behaviour -- but I have come across a scenario where I need one of my section headers to remain on the top, even if a second section header wants to push it off.

In this scenario, I would ideally like the second section header to "stack" beneath the first section header.

Comment: This should be possible with a `UITableView` by manually forcing the positions of the headers in `scrollViewDidScroll:`. You would need to check what sections are currently visible and have a reference to the section headers so you can manipulate their frame inside the table.

Comment: That said, this is bordering on being too much for a `UITableView` and may be best suited to your own implementation of a `UICollectionView`, where you can make it behave as much or as little like a `UITableView` as you want.